# How do I use field_view_field() to print a user profile picture?

Tags: 7, entities, blocks, users

I'm trying to print a user profile's picture in a block that gets displayed on a node page. I have the nodes author be loaded as in the following code:

```
<?php 
$node = menu_get_object('node');
$user = user_load($node->uid);
?>
```

This is the code I have come up with for the block:

```
<div class="author-block">
  <h4>Meet the author</h4>
  <?php print drupal_render(field_view_field('user', $user, 'picture', 'user-pic-style'));?>
</div>
```

This isn't working and doesn't print anything.
I want the user's picture be loaded if users have one, or the default user picture if they don't.
I have other custom user fields that are printing just fine using the [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7), so I am wondering why I am not having luck.

Comment: May I suggest that you re-title the question to be less specific to a particular function? Just "How do I programmatically render a picture", perhaps?

Comment: If you have the image url, you could do this - 
print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'user-pic-style', 'path' => $user_picture_path));

Comment: Please don't use $user = user_load(... it can conflict with global $user. Use $account = ... instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="author-block">
  <h4>Meet the author</h4>
  <?php print drupal_render(field_view_field('user', $user, 'picture', array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'user-pic-style'))));?>
</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas how to set a class to image?

Comment: You'd have to add a class using a preprocess function separately I believe - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7

Comment: Thanks! I think so too, but didn't try yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why the field isn't returning any data, but I think it has something to do with it being an image, and you not setting a style. Here's how I've done similar things with images before.
Please note that I have altered the code below both to protect my original customer, and to hide the fact this was done as a Ctools plugin, instead of a block. So there could be minor issues like misspellings and the like. My apologies if that's the case.

```
// Create a shortcut to the image we want to render
$image_data = $image_node->field_images[LANGUAGE_NONE][0];

// Image rendering data
$variables = array(
  'style_name' => 'blurb_208x208',
  'path' => $image_data['filename'],
  'alt' => '',
  'title' => '',
);

$styles = image_styles(); // Get all available styles
$style = $styles['blurb_208x208'];

// We are responsible ourselves for ensuring the derived image is available.
$derivative_uri = image_style_path($style['name'], $path_to_original_image);
if (!file_exists($derivative_uri)) {
  image_style_create_derivative(
    $style,
    $image_data['uri'],
    $derivative_uri
  );
}

$markup = '<div class="image-wrapper">' . theme('image_style', $variables) . '</div>';
```